# Partial string match and lookup in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, custom-functions-excel

I'm pretty lost with something I have to do with Excel.

I need to make a recursive lookup between two tables to find a match, and insert a specific value in one cell.

In the next example, I show you what should be done, I hope anyone could help! :)

Basically, I need to look for values from column "E" within each "B" cell, and if there is any match, insert the specific "F" value in "C".

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyqo8.png)

[Error after increasing range of Trigger column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVB9Y.png)

[3rd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uef7j.png)

I don't know if a formula is enough, but maybe a macro is needed.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful: when working with recursion in Excel formulas, you might get at "circular reference" error. This link explains how to handle this (or not): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF using dictionary. If no match found it will return blank. Instead of parsing the Text column cell it loops through Trigger column's dictionary keys to find match in the Text columns cell value.

`dict.CompareMode` is set to be `vbTextCompare` for non-case senseitive comparison to find matches. For case sensitive comparison we can set this to `vbBinaryCompare`

[excelmacromastery Page](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20VBA%20Dictionary%3F%20In%20VBA%20we,cells.%20A%20Dictionary%20is%20similar%20to%20a%20Collection.)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function PartialStrMatch(str As String, matchCol As Range, lookupCol As Range) As String
Dim dict As Object, i As Long, cl As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For Each cl In matchCol
    If Not dict.exists(cl.Value) Then
    dict.Add cl.Value, lookupCol(Application.Match(cl, matchCol, 0)).Value
    End If
Next cl

For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    If InStr(1, str, dict.Keys()(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        PartialStrMatch = dict.Items()(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for your replay, it works for me but till 10 trigger values. How could I change the function to allow like 10K possible trigger values for example? :S 
Regards!!

Comment: Just change the range in the formula like $E$2:$E$10000 and so for F column.. [If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Comment: I show you what I mean, in the body of my post.
Thank you!! :)

Comment: thanks for your support, I really appreciate it.
What I've seen in my test (i update my post), is that for example, it seems like the trigger starts from below, so for case "Seat" for example, it writes value "Not a car" instead of "Car" because in some place there is an "E", and if I add a trigger called "Z" and the text contains that letter, it writes that value. 
Any idea?

Comment: @CrisoNikon .. code edited with adding "Exit for" in the second loop. Not it will take only the first match... But if you insert E or Z in the first then it will take for those values and not cars

Comment: You are right, I update the last screenshot with that information. 
As you can see, it starts matching from below instead as from above, would you be able to change it? I don't know how to do it.
In my example, as "S" of "Seat" is matched before "Seat", it writes "Detected "S" instead of Seat, and for some reason, the rest do the same :S

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$3,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF($B1,"*"&$E$1:$E$3&"*")>0),0)),"No matching values")`
Wrapping the trigger range in `"*"` makes it accept all characters before or after the search string

Comment: Hello @P.b, I'm getting almost always value "No matching values" :S Any other idea? Thank you so much for your replay!

Comment: I tested it and it spilled wrong results. I adjusted the formula so it doesn't spill and works correctly.